# How to remove an User from a file, using Cywin or Powershell

Tags: powershell, cygwin

Thank you very much in advance for helping.

So I have hundreds of files and folders from which I'd like to remove the user: C850-108.
I can do this using Windows interface, but it'd take me days to do it in every file.

The reason I'd like to do this is because Cobian Backup tool can't have access to this files (Permission denied) and I think that user is the problem.

So I have Cygwin (bash) an PowerShell to help me in this tedious task.

I attach 3 screenshots:

1. Windows Security tab

   [image]
2. PowerShell output of the command `get-acl | format-list`

   [image]
3. Cygwin output of `getfacl`

   [image]

I'm more experienced with bash, so I tried adding an user like this:

```
 setfacl.exe -m u:rafaelgp:rwx myfile
```

Which apparently did nothing, but when I check with PowerShell, I saw that it actually worked and added a new user (rafaelgp) with the specified permissions. You can see this in the screenshots. So after this I lost some trust in Cygwin.

I've also tried deleting the user like this:

```
setfacl.exe -d u:C850-108 myfile
```

But I get the following message:

```
setfacl: illegal acl entries
```

So what can I do? As I said, I'm happy trying anything using bash or PowerShell.

Cheers!

UPDATE:

Screenshot of Musaab Al-Okaidi solution. There seems to be a problem with the '$file' parameter

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would arguably be [`icacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
icacls file /remove C850-180
```

You can't remove permissions that were inherited from the parent folder with this, though. I suspect that this is the reason why `setfacl` failed. Unfortunately the inheritance information is suppressed when you pipe the output of `Get-Acl` into `Format-List`. Try this instead:

```
Get-Acl file | % { $_.Access } | ? { $_.IdentityReference -match 'C850-180' }
```

The `IsInherited` property will show you whether or not the ACL is inherited. If the ACL is inherited, you have to disable inheritance first before you can remove an ACL:

```
icacls file /inheritance:d
```

`icacls` is [available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919240) since Windows Server 2003 SP2.

**Update:**

You can apply this recursively to a folder tree by adding the option `/t`:

```
icacls C:\some\folder\* /t /inheritance:d
icacls C:\some\folder\* /t /remove C850-180
```

Be advised, though, that it's *not* a good idea to recursively disable inheritance as it will make managing permissions a nightmare. Depending on your folder structure it might be better to simply remove inheritance and that particular ACE from the parent folder:

```
icacls C:\some\folder /inheritance:d
icacls C:\some\folder /remove C850-180
```

The subfolders and files will automatically inherit their parent folder's changed permissions. If necessary you can enforce that by resetting permissions on subfolders and files:

```
icacls C:\some\folder\* /reset /t /c
```

Comment: IsInherited was actually enabled. icalcs file /inheritance:d disabled it successfull and I was able to delete that user using the code you supplied. Any chance to adapt that code to work recursively in folders instead of file by file? Many many thanks!

Comment: What if I disable inheritance and then enable it back once I've removed that user?

Comment: @RafaelGP Then the ACE you just removed will be inherited again. Inheritance is all or nothing. You can't inherit ACEs selectively.

Comment: @RafaelGP Addendum: What you *can* do when you don't want to break inheritance is to add a **deny** ACE for `C850-180`. That will take precedence over the inherited *allow* ACE and prevent the account from accessing the files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function to your shell, simply copy and paste, then you will have `Remove-UserAccess` as a usable Cmdlet

```
Function Remove-UserAccess()
{
   Param
   (   
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$Path,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$User      
   )

   $Files = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
   $Files.Add($Path) | Out-Null

   #Add all files and folders to an array
   $PathSubtree = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse
   Foreach ( $File in $PathSubtree )
   {
      $Files.Add($File.FullName) | Out-Null
   }

   # Remove access of the $User from each file in the array
   Foreach ( $File in $Files )
   {
      $AccessRule = Get-Acl $File | % { $_.Access } | ? {  $_.IdentityReference -eq $User}
      IF ( $AccessRule -eq $null )
      {
         Write-Host "$User does not have access to $File" -ForegroundColor Yellow
      }
      ELSE
      {
         $ACL = Get-Acl $File
         $ACL.RemoveAccessRule($AccessRule) | out-Null
         Set-Acl -Path $File -AclObject $ACL -ErrorAction Stop
         Write-Host "Permissions for $user have been removed from the following path: $File" -ForegroundColor Green
      }
   }
}
```

Execute the command as follows:

```
Remove-UserAccess -Path C:\temp -User RAFALAPTOP\C850-108
```

This will remove the access for the user from C:\temp and all sub-files and folders.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I attached a screenshot at the bottom of my question. There is a problem with $file

Comment: Did you set the $file variable? This should be the path to the file or folder you want to modify. Alternatively you can just hard code the path in.
I just used that variable as a place holder

Comment: Also, make sure you change the "domain\user" to your specific user which i believe is "RAFALAPTOP\C850-108"

Comment: It works for individual files and folders! Well done! I'll be happy to click your answer as correct if you can make it recursive. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: if all the files are in a folder, use `Get-ChildItem $varwithfolderpath -Recurse | % { $accessrule = get-acl $_ | .. rest of his answer... }`. If you have an array of filepaths, use: `$arrayoffilepaths | % { $access......`

Comment: Hi Rafael,
I've put it in a function(I've edited the original answer), so now you can use it on files and folders recursively.

Comment: Didn't this function do the job for you?